# MySQL Tables Disappearing

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1, mysql-5.7

I am having an issue with MySQL. I recently needed to rebuild my computer because of a virus that I got on it. Everything with the rebuild went smoothly, but I am having a hard time getting MySQL to behave itself. The configuration file for my database is exactly the same as it was before, but I am having an issue with certain tables disappearing after restarting MySQL.

Here's a segment from the error log that I believe details this issue:

```
2014-03-06T21:02:13.043598Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.3-m13-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2014-03-06T21:02:33.191623Z 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table "testschema_testwithunderscore"."testtable_withunderscore" in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 57.
2014-03-06 16:02:33 0x1d64  InnoDB: Operating system error number 32 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means that another program is using InnoDB's files.
InnoDB: This might be a backup or antivirus software or another instance
InnoDB: of MySQL. Please close it to get rid of this error.
2014-03-06T21:02:33.194622Z 5 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'testschema_testwithunderscore/testtable_withunderscore'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-03-06 16:02:33 0x1d64 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "testschema_testwithunderscore"."testtable_withunderscore" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-06 16:02:33 0x1d64 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "testschema_testwithunderscore"."testtable_withunderscore" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-06 16:02:33 0x1d64 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "testschema_testwithunderscore"."testtable_withunderscore" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-06 16:02:34 0x1d64 InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "testschema_testwithunderscore"."testtable_withunderscore" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
2014-03-06 16:02:39 0x1d9c InnoDB: cannot calculate statistics for table "testschema_testwithunderscore"."testtable_withunderscore" because the .ibd file is missing. For help, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html
```

I posted this question once before but nobody seemed to fully understand my problem. To make it easier to understand the issue, please watch [this video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9tiL42zIwVeZjJHVWtHbktHaXc/edit) showing me creating a test schema and test table, restarting the database, and watching it disappear. The folder that I have open is the ProgramData folder for MySQL server. **As a sidenote, this strange behavior of disappearing tables does not occur when I set `lower_case_table_names` to `1`. I would like to be able to user uppercase characters in my tables names as I have done in the past.**

Comment: Have you tried the advice in the error message of disabling anti-virus and making sure no backup is already using the innodb file?

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms Yes. I have tried disabling Malwarebytes and it still has the same problem. In the past I used a server with the same configuration in Windows 8.1 Pro with Windows Defender and it didn't cause problems.

Comment: Mate, you get +1 just for your About Me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved for a while now, but I forgot about this question until today so I'll come back and answer it. Apparently my installation of MySQL Server was corrupt in some way, and reinstalling the server solved the problem.